# How open image with tag a?

Tags: html, npm, webpack

To create my page i use webpack. In page i want show multiple image. On internet i found library "lightbox2". This library is used for click image and popup. The library have simple example like this:

```
    <a
  class="example-image-link"
  href="../image/bed-small.jpg" -- not work
  href="./469cccac29babd05add3a0b2d23abf0d.jpg" -- work
  data-lightbox="example-1"
  ><img class="example-image" src="../image/bed-small.jpg" alt="image-1" --here work
/></a>
```

Img src work great and i see picture on my page. When i click on image popup work but image never loaded. I used dev-tools and i see that my image is download with that name '469cccac29babd05add3a0b2d23abf0d.jpg'. So i copy and i see my image. My question is how generate that file name dynamic in my html file ? Below i add my webpack.conf

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
  },
  entry: {
    main: './js/index.js',
    fontAwesome: './js/fontAwe.js',
    fontSolid: './js/fontSolid.js',
    fontRegular: './js/fontRegular.js',
    galery: './js/galery.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({ cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'none',
      template: './index.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['main', 'fontAwesome', 'fontSolid', 'fontRegular'],
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'none',
      template: './pages/galeria.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['galery'],
      filename: 'galeria.html',
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              // Prefer `dart-sass`
              implementation: require('sass'),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        //IMAGE LOADER
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'fonts/',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

My dev-tool
[image]

No longer current. I found solution. Import image to js file and changed href ;)

Answer (score 0):

change name of photo and use:`<div class=""><a src="></a>`

Comment: it don't work. I tried use src in a tag. Webpack not generate image file. It still path like that src="../image/bed-small.jpg"

Comment: than use it in css        background-image= url(" ");